# cant preform an if statement correctly

Tags: if-statement, lua

This has been bugging me for a long time, I've been making a program that simply preforms an action if you type in a certain password. I keep getting a error saying ":4: '' expected or "if statement expected" Please help!

```
 textutils.SlowPrint("type the password")
--This is a W.I.P and it is in a basic stage!
pass = ImCool
setCursorPos.(4,5)
input.read(*)
--problem is here
if input = pass then
print("You did it"!)
```

Comment: This is not valid Lua code.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to check for equality, use the `==` operator, like so:

```
if input == pass then
    print("You did it")
end
```

You're using `=` right now.

Your code has other typos as well - there's a `.` after `setCursorPos` and the `!` is outside the double quotes. `ImCool` - is this a symbol or a string? If it's a string, it should be in double quotes.

I'm not sure about that `input.read(*)` line - it doesn't seem right but I haven't used Lua for a while. I remember using `io.read()` to get command-line input in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no lua expert, but it looks like you should have quotes around `ImCool` when you assign it to `pass`:

```
pass = "ImCool"
```

I know your problem is happening at a later line of code, but mistakes like this can mess with the parser.

Check out the Strings section at http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTypesTutorial for initializing string variables.

Also, I don't know if it got cut off when you copied your code, but you probably need `end` after your if-statement.  You also probably meant to use the `==` operator instead of `=` on the if-statement.  See http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html for details.